# How to pause voice guidance in heremaps for a period of time in android SDK?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am working on a scenario where I will have to pause here maps voice guidance (android SDK) for sometime and provide my own audio using Google tts.

Currently it works with a delay of few s

e.g : if there are 4 voice instructions from here maps , all four are completed first and then plays my audio. What API should I use so that I can abruptly pause heremaps voice guidance Audio and play my audio ?

API s to be used to control voice guidance from here maps in android SDK would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To stop currently played audio use NavigationManager.getAudioPlayer().stop().
Then use NavigationManager.setEnabledAudioEvents() to enable/disable audio events during navigation.

Comment: How to disable and enable voice guidance audio in here maps  ?   Can u share an example snippet using the interface NavigationManager.setEnabledAudioEvents() ? For more clarity    e.g what parameters to pass in the setenabledaudioevents() call and handling it